# Writing a value on a line, but it's pushes the others

Tags: c#

I wanted to update my hangman game, with more than 3 letter words, and now as I added more and started typing it in, it pushes the other value, for example if I add the letter "R" to the value, it prints it, but not to it's correct spot, as I add more, for example, the word is "FEAR", as I add, "E" and then "A" the letter "R" starts to shift to it's correct position.

I tried deleting a few spaces, but then eventhough it would be on the correct spot if I guess it for the first time, if I guess another letter it just starts being pushed to the right. After I guessed all the letters the letters jump to their correct spot, but I'd like to be able to make this one as, well flawless as I can.

The firstPlace contains the first letter of the word, the secondPlace contains the second and so on. On those lines are supposed to be the letters when you run the game.

Thanks for the reply, have a nice day!

```
//first attempt

Console.WriteLine($" {firstPlace}    {secondPlace}    {thirdPlace}     {fourthPlace}\n" +
               "---  ---  ---  ---\n\n");
//second attempt
Console.Write(" " + firstPlace);
Console.Write("    " + secondPlace);
Console.Write("    " + thirdPlace);
Console.Write("    " + fourthPlace);

Console.WriteLine("\n---  ---  ---  ---\n\n");
```

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand, but you might want to look at [alignment component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting#alignment-component)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it actually helped and finished it, String.Format solved the whole pushing, again, thanks very much!